# SharpDX StrokeStyle1

Tags: c#, sharpdx

How do I use `StrokeStyle1` from SharpDX? I have a `Factory`, a `StrokeStyleProperties1`, and other parameters, but the constructor for `StrokeStyle1` only accepts a `Factory1`. How do I get an instance of `Factory1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `Factory.QueryInterface<Factory1>()`.